# Symfony Authentication after register

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a mini web project and i'm building it in symfony, so after i created registeration and login form, i realised that after registration user won't be directly authenticated, so i made some research to see how it works but i'm facing some problems and i'm new to this framework.
Here's the controller code (the users class is called Players in my app because i'm developping an escape game)

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
use App\Entity\Items;
use App\Entity\Players;
use App\Entity\Inventaire;
use App\Security\TokenAuthenticator;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\GuardAuthenticatorHandler;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;


class PlayerController extends AbstractController

{
    private $em;
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    
    $this->em = $entityManager;
}
/**
 * @Route("/player", name="player")
 */
public function index(): Response
{
    return $this->render('player/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'PlayerController',
    ]);
}
/**
 * @Route("/login_Player", name="login_Player")
 */
public function loginPlayer(){
    return $this->render("app/player_interface.html.twig");
}
/**
 * @Route("/redirect_player", name="redirect_player")
 */
public function redirectPlayer(){
    $player = $this->getUser();
    if($player){
        return $this->render("app/player_interface.html.twig",['player'=>$player]);
    }
    else{
        return $this-render("app/home.html.twig");
    }
    
}

/**
 * @Route("/logout_Player", name="logout_Player")
 */
public function logoutPlayer(){
    return $this->render("app/home.html.twig");
}
/**
 * @Route("/create_interface", name="create_Player")
 */
public function createPlayer(Request $request,EntityManagerInterface $em,UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder,GuardAuthenticatorHandler $guardHandler,TokenAuthenticator $authenticator): Response
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Players::class);
    if($request->request->count()>0){
        if(($repository->findBy(["username"=>$request->request->get("pseudo")])) || ($repository->findBy(["email"=>$request->request->get("mail")]))){
            return $this->render("app/home.html.twig",["msg"=>"Id ou mail déja utilisé!"]);
        }
        else{
            $coord=[48.8413672,2.4223428];
            $player = new Players();
            $player->setUsername($request->request->get("pseudo"))
                   ->setPassword($request->request->get("pass"))
                   ->setEmail($request->request->get("mail"));
            $player->setLongitude($coord[1]);
            $player->setLatitude($coord[0]);
            $inventaire=new Inventaire();
            $inventaire->setPlayerId($player);
            $player->setInventaire($inventaire);
            $this->em=$em;
            $hash=$encoder->encodePassword($player, $player->getPassword());
            $player->setPassword($hash);
            $em->persist($player);
            $em->persist($inventaire);
            $em->flush();
            return $guardHandler->authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess($player,$request,$authenticator,'main');
            //return $this->render("app/player_interface.html.twig",['player'=>$player]);//'inventaire'=>$inventaire]);
        }

    }

}
/**
 * @Route("/add_item",name="add_item")
 */
public function addItem(Request $request,EntityManagerInterface $em){
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        $this->em=$em;
        $player = $this->getUser();
        $inventaire=$player->getInventaire();
        $item=new Items();
        $item->setDescription($request->request->get("description"))
             ->setVisibility($request->request->get("visibility"))
             ->setNiveau($request->request->get("icon_id"));
        $inventaire->addItemId($item);
        $em->flush();
        return new JsonResponse(array("player"=>$player,"inventaire"=>$inventaire->getItem_id()));
    }
    else{
        return $this->render("app/player_interface.html.twig");
    }
}

/**
 * @Route("/move_player",name="move_player")
 */
public function movePlayer(Request $request,EntityManagerInterface $em){
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        $this->em=$em;
        $player = $this->getUser();
        $player->setLongitude($request->request->get("longitude"))
               ->setLatitude($request->request->get("latitude"));
        $em->flush();
        return new JsonResponse(array("player"=>$player));
    }
    else{
        return $this->render("app/player_interface.html.twig");
    }

}
/**
 * @Route("affiche_scenario", name="affiche_scenario")
 */
public function afficheScenario(Request $request){
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Scenarios::class);
        return new JsonResponse($repository->findBy($request->request->get("num_scenario")));
    }
    else{
        return $this->render("app/player_interface.html.twig");
    }
}
}
?>
```

and this is the tokenauthenticator class:

```
    <?php
// src/Security/TokenAuthenticator.php
namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

class TokenAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    private $em;
    protected $router;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em,HttpUtils $httpUtils, $router)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->router = $router;
}

/**
 * Called on every request to decide if this authenticator should be
 * used for the request. Returning `false` will cause this authenticator
 * to be skipped.
 */
public function supports(Request $request)
{
    return $request->headers->has('X-AUTH-TOKEN');
}

/**
 * Called on every request. Return whatever credentials you want to
 * be passed to getUser() as $credentials.
 */
public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->headers->get('X-AUTH-TOKEN');
}

public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    if (null === $credentials) {
        // The token header was empty, authentication fails with HTTP Status
        // Code 401 "Unauthorized"
        return null;
    }

    // The "username" in this case is the apiToken, see the key `property`
    // of `your_db_provider` in `security.yaml`.
    // If this returns a user, checkCredentials() is called next:
    return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials);
}

public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
{
    // Check credentials - e.g. make sure the password is valid.
    // In case of an API token, no credential check is needed.

    // Return `true` to cause authentication success
    return true;
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    
        /*if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }*/
        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('redirect_player'));
        

    
}

public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    $data = [
        // you may want to customize or obfuscate the message first
        'message' => strtr($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData())

        // or to translate this message
        // $this->translator->trans($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData())
    ];

    return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
}

/**
 * Called when authentication is needed, but it's not sent
 */
public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
{
    $data = [
        // you might translate this message
        'message' => 'Authentication Required'
    ];

    return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
}

public function supportsRememberMe()
{
    return false;
    }
}
?>
```

And finaly the security.yaml file

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\Players:
        algorithm: bcrypt
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers

providers:
    users_in_memory: { memory: null }
    in_database:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Players
            property: username
firewalls:
dev:
    pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false
main:
    anonymous: true
    lazy: true
    #provider: users_in_memory
    provider: in_database

    form_login:
        login_path: login_Player
        check_path: login_Player
        #failure_handler: App\Security\authentication_failure_handler
        csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
        failure_path: home
    guard:
        authenticators:
            - App\Security\TokenAuthenticator
    logout:
        path: logout_Player
        target: home



    # activate different ways to authenticate
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication



      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

The TokenAuthenticator class i found it on symfony and another tutorial so i don't really understand the mechanism and when i try to register a user now, the app shows me an error:
Cannot autowire service "App\Security\TokenAuthenticator": argument "$router" of method "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.

Thanks in advance everyone and have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html

> Autowiring allows you to manage services in the container with minimal configuration. It reads the type-hints on your constructor (or other methods) and automatically passes the correct services to each method. Symfony’s autowiring is designed to be predictable: if it is not absolutely clear which dependency should be passed, you’ll see an actionable exception.

You must type hint your arguments passed to the constructor so that symfony can pass them to you automatically thanks to autowiring:

```php
// others uses
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class TokenAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    private $em;
    protected $router;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, HttpUtils $httpUtils, RouterInterface $router)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->router = $router;
}
```

Or if you want juste to generate urls, you cant use the UrlGeneratorInterface instead of the router:

```php
// ...
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class TokenAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    private $em;
    protected $urlGenerator;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, HttpUtils $httpUtils, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('redirect_player'));
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your help i appreciate it.